# zig maxValue of integer and float types

Tags: zig

zig used to have [@maxValue](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.3.0/#maxValue) to query the max value for integer types, but I think it was removed several versions ago. Is there a replacement? I can´t find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std.math.maxInt()`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:math.maxInt).